# How to retrieve and update HBase Tables from Spark in Scala

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hive, hbase

It seems no proper resources or documentation or books available to access HBase tables as we have for HIve , I'm creating Hbase configuration and sacnning and trying to Put but missing some links how to do that (just copying and pasting from forums and github but unable to understand) , can any one post an end-to-end code to  retrieve and update Hbase table in detail??

Or any Hbase books/blogs recommended to access from spark

Comment: refer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25040709/how-to-read-from-hbase-using-spark) and the [Hbase Junit Test](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/HBaseTest.scala)

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the following question :

[How to read from hbase using Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25040709/how-to-read-from-hbase-using-spark)

Also for writing up the data you can use the following library :

[Spark HBase connector](https://github.com/nerdammer/spark-hbase-connector)

It have a good documentation on Reading and writing up the data to Hbase and also if you're good in the SQL part it supports almost of the operations in SQL too.

Please comment below if you need to understand anything more in it.

Comment: Recommendations for learning resources [are off-topic for stackoverflow.com Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). However, this information [could _maybe_ be ok as part of a tag wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214338/997587).