# Apache Spark/Scala Bulk inset/update to HBASE

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hbase

Below is my scenario:

1. Initially load data to **HBASE** using **Sqoop** (This is done)
2. Now, I will get batches of data on daily basis (around 600000 records) which is a combination of new data (for inserting the new records to HBASE)  and old data (for updating the existing records of HBASE). Now my question is:

How can I perform this operation using **Spark/scala** to **Hbase** table.

Your early reply would be highly appreciated.

Thanks
Souvik

Comment: Which API (RDDs, DataFrames, Datasets) and Spark version are you using?

Comment: Hi Anton, I am using the spark version 1.6.1 and API is dataframe.

Comment: If you provide me any sample code, that will really help me.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to read answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25040709/how-to-read-from-hbase-using-spark) to get an overview.

In [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25040709/how-to-read-from-hbase-using-spark/41148230#41148230) there, I mention several options that you can use:

- [hbase-spark](https://github.com/apache/hbase/tree/master/hbase-spark), a module that is available directly in the HBase repo
- [Spark-on-HBase](https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/shc/tree/branch-1.6) by Hortonworks

Since you are using Spark 1.6.1, you can use any of them. An example of working with DataFrames in hbase-spark can be found [here](https://github.com/apache/hbase/blob/master/hbase-spark/src/main/scala/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/spark/example/datasources/HBaseSource.scala), while a similar example for Spark-on-HBase can be found [here](https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/shc/blob/branch-1.6/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/hbase/HBaseSource.scala).

Comment: Hi Anton: If I use Hive-on-Hbase package (yum install hive-hbase) for bulk insert/update operation then which API will give better performance? I can execute this command through Spak itsel.