# spark 1.3 playing with hbase error

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, spark-streaming

i'm trying to create hbase table and insert using spark core (spark streaming after). 
I succeeded to create the table and add data into it, even when i got this problem:

```
warning: Class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.classification.InterfaceAudience not found - continuing with a stub.
```

but when i try to count i got an error; may someone help me with the first warning and how i cant add streaming data into this table

my code is bellow:

```
            import org.apache.spark._
            import org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD
            import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.{HBaseConfiguration, HTableDescriptor}
            import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin
            import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormat
            import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
            import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HColumnDescriptor
            import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes
            import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put;
            import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable;
            import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapred.TableOutputFormat
            import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf
            import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable
            import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job
            import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat
            import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat
            import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.KeyValue
            import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.HFileOutputFormat
            import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles
        val tableName = "ziedspark" 
        val conf = HBaseConfiguration.create()
        conf.addResource(new Path("file:///opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.7-1.cdh5.4.7.p0.3/etc/hbase/conf.dist/hbase-site.xml"))
    conf.set(TableInputFormat.INPUT_TABLE, tableName)
    val admin = new HBaseAdmin(conf)
        if(!admin.isTableAvailable(tableName)) {
          print("Creating GHbase Table Creating GHbase Table Creating GHbase Table Creating GHbase Table ")
          val tableDesc = new HTableDescriptor(tableName)
          tableDesc.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor("z1".getBytes()))
          tableDesc.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor("z2".getBytes()))
          admin.createTable(tableDesc)

        }else{
          print("Table already exists!!")
        }
 val myTable = new HTable(conf, tableName)
    for (i <- 414540 to 414545) {

      var p = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(""+i))
      p.add("z1".getBytes(), "name".getBytes(), Bytes.toBytes(""+(i*5)))
      p.add("z1".getBytes(), "age".getBytes(), Bytes.toBytes("2016-07-01"))
      p.add("z2".getBytes(), "job".getBytes(), Bytes.toBytes(""+i))
      p.add("z2".getBytes(), "salary".getBytes(), Bytes.toBytes(""+i))
      myTable.put(p)
    }

    myTable.flushCommits()


       val hBaseRDD = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(conf, classOf[TableInputFormat],
 classOf[org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable],
 classOf[org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result])

            //error here after creating the table count is not working
        val count = hBaseRDD.count()
    print("HBase RDD count:" + count)
    System.exit(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find a similar question related to the Reading from Spark.

[How to read from hbase using spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25040709/how-to-read-from-hbase-using-spark/28698555#28698555)

Also in the mentioned libraries you'll get the stub to read and write in HBase.

Let me know for any more help on the same.

Comment: i got a problem with this import:`import it.nerdammer.spark.hbase._`  even when i add the all the jars; i'm using spark shell

Comment: `spark-shell --jars spark-streaming-kafka_2.10-1.3.0.jar kafka_2.10-0.8.0.jar spark-hbase-connector_2.10-1.0.3\(2\).jar`